# Who wants the Cerberus automated turret schematics?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just found the Cerberus automated turret schematics on Tuchanka and got a corresponding entry in my journal that someone on the Citadel might be interested in those.

Who on the Citadel wants those turret schematics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to wait until after Priority: Citadel 2. The "someone on the Citadel" you're referring to is a C-Sec officer who will appear in the Presidium Commons after the previously mentioned event.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a C-SEC officer in the Presidium commons on the Citadel.  He should be on the level overlooking the shops.